# How to change the size of a unicode or image using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, unicode

I have a table whose data gets changed dynamically. If a particular condition is satisfied, then I want to show an image and if not then another image.

I used unicode, but it was too small and the png file is too large.

Here is the code

```
if (game['B'] != game['A'])
   $('<img>').attr('src','symbol.png').appendTo(tr);
   //$('<td></td>').text("\uD83D\uDC4D").appendTo(tr);
else
   $('<td></td>').text("\uD83D\uDC4E").appendTo(tr);
```

How can I change the size of it through here?

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: use css to change "font-size" ... or CSS to change image dimensions (width, height, both)

Comment: @JaromandaX how do I use css here? This has no reference elsewhere. So I cannot take the id or anything.

Comment: inline `style` attribute ... or, since you're using jquery .. `$('<td></td>').css('font-size', '2em').text("\uD83D\uDC4E").appendTo(tr);` for example

Comment: @JaromandaX I needed the JQuery part. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would use CSS. But there is a way to do what you're asking right there to make things neat... Let's assume you what the width of the pic to be 100px, here's what you would use (untested). For a complete list of CSS properties available, which can be used with the added .css field, please refer to:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/

```
if (game['B'] != game['A']) {
    $('<img>').attr('src','symbol.png').css('width', '100px').appendTo(tr);
} else {
    $('<td></td>').text("\uD83D\uDC4E").appendTo(tr);  
}
```